Finding generators of Aschbacher subgroups
Aschbacher famously showed that the maximal subgroups of the finite classical groups can be split into various categories. How does one find explicit generators for these groups, when the field is left arbitrary? Is there a standard way?
As an example, the maximal subgroups of $GL_5(q)$ are known and categorized, but how does one find a explicit generating set for them?

The two papers
Paper 1 D.F. Holt and C.M. Roney-Dougal,   Constructing maximal subgroups of classical groups. LMS J. Comput. Math. 8 (2005), 46 -79, and
Paper 2 D.F. Holt and C.M. Roney-Dougal,  Constructing maximal subgroups of orthogonal groups. LMS J. Comput. Math. 13 (2010),  164-191
are devoted to solving precisely this problem, at least for the first eight of the Aschbacher classes. The ninth class consists of absolutely irreducible subgroups that are almost simple modulo scalars, and they do not have a uniform description.
You can also access all of the subgroups (including the ninth class up to dimension 17) in Magma using the command $\mathtt{ClassicalMaximals}$.

I had come across the first paper, but it seemed to only concern computation in a fixed field, akin to how Magma will only work with specific groups, but not a family. I'll go read through it again.

Required fighting with some typos, but this paper is exactly what I need.
